# load_file is skipping null bytes

Tags: c, file

I am trying to understand the behavior of the `load_file` function in c. I have a simple test program that loads a binary into memory using `load_file` and loops through it printing each byte.

```c
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  int file_descriptor = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
  unsigned int file_size = get_file_size(file_descriptor);
  unsigned int* instruction_bytes = load_file(file_descriptor, file_size);
  close(file_descriptor);
  unsigned int num_instructions = file_size / 4;
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < num_instructions; i++) {
    printf("%02x", instruction_bytes[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

EDIT here are the missing functions, I didn't realize these weren't standard C functions. This is part of a larger learning project, and I'm not that familiar with C.

```c
/*
 * Returns the file size in bytes of the file referred to by the given descriptor
*/
unsigned int get_file_size(int file_descriptor)
{
  struct stat file_stat;
  fstat(file_descriptor, &file_stat);
  return file_stat.st_size;
}

/*
 * Loads the raw bytes of a file into an array of 4-byte units
*/
unsigned int* load_file(int file_descriptor, unsigned int size)
{
  unsigned int* raw_instruction_bytes = (unsigned int*)malloc(size);
  if(raw_instruction_bytes == NULL)
    error_exit("unable to allocate memory for instruction bytes (something went really wrong)");

  int num_read = read(file_descriptor, raw_instruction_bytes, size);

  if(num_read != size)
    error_exit("unable to read file (something went really wrong)");

  return raw_instruction_bytes;
}
```

When I pass a known file to this program something strange happens. I know the first 8 byes of this file to be `08 00 00 00 00 00 00 B2` but when I run this program the 5th iteration prints `B2` instead of `00`. Gdb reports that immediately after the file is loaded, for bytes offset from the base address of the file indeed is `B2`. What happened to the `00` bytes between offset 3 and `B2`

Comment: Where do `get_file_size` and `load_file` come from?

Comment: The `load_file` I know of is for databases.  Please add the #include where this is defined.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Yes it will. The size field specifies a minimum size, not maximum.

Comment: `load_file()` is not a standard C function.

Comment: It probably should be `unsigned char *` rather than `unsigned int*`

Comment: sorry added the missing functions. See the edits

Comment: Hint: read carefully about what the `printf` specifier `%02x` does; in particular what happens with leading zeros.  Think about what it will do if passed the value `0xb2 == 0x000000b2`.

Comment: @NateEldredge I understand 0x000000b2 == 0xb2, what I am not sure about is how the `read` function is working inside `load_file`. Does is truncate the zeros in memory also?

Comment: You aren't losing anything in the read.  "00 00 00 B2 " fits in one int.

Comment: @richbai90: The read function is perfectly fine, and there is nothing wrong with `load_file()`.  If the second int in your file is `0x000000b2`, then `instruction_bytes[1]` will indeed contain `0x000000b2`, but since `printf` doesn't print the leading zeros, `printf("%02x", instruction_bytes[1]);` will only output `b2`, not `000000b2` which you were hoping for.  Do you see what I mean?  I suspect you wanted `%08x`.

Comment: I'm not sure I would agree with the statememtn "there is nothing wrong with `load_file()`".   That function should return an `unsigned char *`, not an `unsigned int *`.   Returning int instead of char is causing unnecessary confusion, IMO.

Comment: The printf was just a test, I what I really need is to go through this file a byte at a time and interpret it based on the byte position. So I need to know for instance that instruction_bytes[1] is 00 even when it is just a leading zero in the sequence

Comment: Note that the OP writes "loops through it printing each byte", and clearly is thinking that `load_file` returned a char, not an int.

Comment: The `get_file_size()` and `load_file()` functions will both fail miserably with files larger than 2 GB on systems with 32-bit integer values.  And `read()` returns `ssize_t`, not `int`.  Are these functions provided to you?  In a learning environment?  Teaching sloppiness like that is horrible.  Precision matters in programming, and providing bad implementations is evidence of low standards or incompetence.

Comment: failing on files larger that 2GB is acceptable, but that failure must be handled!  Even if it is just printing an error message and aborting.  An even bigger problem is providing a function to find the size of a file.  Think of files as a stream; although you *can* compute the size of a regular file, you almost always should not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simplest solution is to fix your loop so that you actually go through the file one byte at a time.  That is:

```
char *instruction_bytes = (char *)load_file(file_descriptor, file_size);
for(int i = 0; i < file_size; i++) {
        printf("%02x", instruction_bytes[i]);
}
```

Iterating over the data as unsigned int is just causing confusion.